# mod.predict gives more columns than expected

Tags: python, mxnet

I am using MXNet on IRIS dataset which has 4 features and it classifies the flowers as -'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'. My training data has 89 rows. My label data is a row vector of 89 columns. I encoded the flower names into number -0,1,2 as it seems mx.io.NDArrayIter does not accept numpy ndarray with string values. Then I tried to predict using

`re = mod.predict(test_iter)`

I get a result which has the shape 14 * 10.
Why am I getting 10 columns when I have only 3 labels and how do I map these results to my labels. The result of predict is shown below:

> [[ 0.11760861 0.12082944 0.1207106 0.09154381 0.09155304 0.09155869
>   0.09154817 0.09155204 0.09154914 0.09154641] [ 0.1176083 0.12082954 0.12071151 0.09154379 0.09155323 0.09155825
>   0.0915481 0.09155164 0.09154923 0.09154641] [ 0.11760829 0.1208293 0.12071083 0.09154385 0.09155313 0.09155875
>   0.09154838 0.09155186 0.09154932 0.09154625] [ 0.11760861 0.12082901 0.12071037 0.09154388 0.09155303 0.09155875
>   0.09154829 0.09155209 0.09154959 0.09154641] [ 0.11760896 0.12082863 0.12070955 0.09154405 0.09155299 0.09155875
>   0.09154839 0.09155225 0.09154996 0.09154646] [ 0.1176089 0.1208287 0.1207095 0.09154407 0.09155297 0.09155882
>   0.09154844 0.09155232 0.09154989 0.0915464 ] [ 0.11760896 0.12082864 0.12070941 0.09154408 0.09155297 0.09155882
>   0.09154844 0.09155234 0.09154993 0.09154642] [ 0.1176088 0.12082874 0.12070983 0.09154399 0.09155302 0.09155872
>   0.09154837 0.09155215 0.09154984 0.09154641] [ 0.11760852 0.12082904 0.12071032 0.09154394 0.09155304 0.09155876
>   0.09154835 0.09155209 0.09154959 0.09154631] [ 0.11760963 0.12082832 0.12070873 0.09154428 0.09155257 0.09155893
>   0.09154856 0.09155177 0.09155051 0.09154671] [ 0.11760966 0.12082829 0.12070868 0.09154429 0.09155258 0.09155892
>   0.09154858 0.0915518 0.09155052 0.09154672] [ 0.11760949 0.1208282 0.12070852 0.09154446 0.09155259 0.09155893
>   0.09154854 0.09155205 0.0915506 0.09154666] [ 0.11760952 0.12082817 0.12070853 0.0915444 0.09155261 0.09155891
>   0.09154853 0.09155206 0.09155057 0.09154668] [ 0.1176096 0.1208283 0.12070892 0.09154423 0.09155267 0.09155882
>   0.09154859 0.09155172 0.09155044 0.09154676]]

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "y = mod.predict(val_iter,num_batch=1)" instead of "y = mod.predict(val_iter)", then you can get only one batch labels. For example,if you batch_size is 10, then you will only  get the 10 labels.

Comment: My dataset has only 3 labels - -'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'. Why is predict method giving me 10 labels

Comment: I guess your model use the wrong num_hidden parameter.  For iris dataset, my model will like these:
net = mx.sym.Variable('data')
net = mx.sym.FullyConnected(net, name='fc2', num_hidden=3)
net = mx.sym.SoftmaxOutput(net, name='softmax',multi_output=True,)
#num_hidden=3 means we output three labels. If you set num_hidden=10,then you will get 10 labels output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was using wrong value of num_hidden